# Disable all Logs

Tags: log, privacy

I use my Ubuntu vps with openvpn as a surf proxy.
For security and privacy reasons i want to disable all logs on the 
server. So no IPs are getting loged in any file.

I already disabled rsyslog daemon, but is there any other daemon / service which 
logs network activity?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    --log-level=<level>
>
>           Sets how much information NetworkManager sends to the log desti���
>           nation (usually syslog's "daemon" facility).  By  default,  only
>           informational, warning, and error messages are logged.  See Net���
>           workManager.conf(5) for  more  information  on  log  levels  and
>           domains.
> ```
>
> man NetworkManager